# In Chrome what is screen_capture_injected?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

when i view the elements using chromes developers tools, in the BODY tag i see

`screen_capture_injected=true`

What does this mean? What does it do? I tried searching for it, but couldnt find anything.

Comment: I don't see it. Try seeing if you can find it when browsing in an incogneto window.  It may be a plugin injecting the attribute.

Comment: Must be from one of your installed extensions.

Comment: it could be, like Joseph said, i used incogneto window and it wasnt, there. i wonder what extension could be doing this. and why its doing it>

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In my case, I have installed the ["Screen Capture" extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg) which I believe is the one adding this attribute.

Comment: ya i think that is the issue at hand.

Answer (score 3):

It is a browser extension injection. I can be from any browser plug-in or extension. It allows newer browsers like chrome to do all the neat things to the web pages that we love (i.e., screen capture, Google voice links, greasemonkey editing, etc.)

Hope that clears it up.